# NetCDF to Geotiff file conversion

Tags: geotiff-tiff, envi, netcdf

How would I convert NetCDF files to Geotiff format? The data I am using is air temperature data that comes from the Climatic Research Institute and I want to display it on ENVI. I am not familiar with writing codes or scripts.

Comment: I tried this but got the error: "...but without any dimensions >=2"

Answer (score 6):

GDAL supports NetCDF: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html

```
gdal_translate input.cdf output.tif
```

Comment: Would you know how I can download the GDAL translate software? there is a huge list of files that appear when I click on the download option

Comment: If you are on Windows, I guess the easiest way is OSGeo4W's bundle: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/NewUserIntroduction On Linux you can simply install it from your repositories. On Mac I don't have a clue.

Comment: With Mac, you can use brew or conda.

Comment: The example command here doesn't work if the netCDF file has multiple subdatasets. The linked page documents it but doesn't give an example. An example might be `gdal_translate NETCDF:"input.cdf":varname output.tif` where `varname` is the name of the subdataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like coding but need an UI, you could check

- GlobalMapper
- [converter.mygeodata.eu](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/)

as mentioned in these [posts](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_we_convert_the_netcdf_data_of_the_cru_to_ascii_or_geotiff_format). Never tried them myself though.

Comment: Hi @nikhil-kumar: why not adding your modification to the post as a comment? That makes it more obvious that this is your annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Convert NetCDF into GeoTiff using [gdal utility](https://www.igismap.com/convert-netcdf-to-geotiff/?utm_source=jnetgeo&utm_medium=stck&utm_campaign=jnetgeo)

Follow the command **> gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:File_Name.nc:Band_Name  -of ‘Gtiff’ Output_FileName.geotiff**

Comment: This is exactly a repost of the top answer, except with more confusing (and unexplained) options in the call.

Comment: And potentially wrong as it assigns a CRS to the data that might not be correct.